# I need to build docker image with postgres with data included

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pg

So, I need docker image with: my program that use postgresql, postgresql and some data in it
I use this article: https://medium.com/@sharmaNK/build-postgres-docker-image-with-data-included-489bd58a1f9e

My steps:

1. `docker-compose build` //Creates ps_image_with_data
2. `docker run --name ps-export -p 5432:5432 -i postgres`
3. Connect to 5432 db, using dbeaver; create table; put some rows in the table
4. `docker exec -it my_container_with_data_id bash`
5. `mkdir /postgres`
6. `cp -r /var/lib/postgresql/data/* /postgres`
7. `docker commit ps-export ps_image_with_data`
8. `docker run --env PGDATA=postgres -p 5432:5432 -i ps_image_with_data` // here I've tried both ps_image_with_data and new image that was created on step 7

And after 8 step I got this:

> 2018-11-08 12:44:52.549 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address
>   "0.0.0.0", port 5432 2018-11-08 12:44:52.549 UTC [1] LOG:  listening
>   on IPv6 address "::", port 5432 2018-11-08 12:44:52.615 UTC [1] LOG: 
>   listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
>   2018-11-08 12:44:52.750 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was
>   interrupted; last known up at 2018-11-08 11:56:27 UTC 2018-11-08
>   12:45:25.042 UTC [22] LOG:  could not remove cache file
>   "global/pg_internal.init": Permission denied 2018-11-08 12:45:25.042
>   UTC [22] LOG:  could not remove cache file
>   "base/13067/pg_internal.init": Permission denied 2018-11-08
>   12:45:25.042 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was not properly shut
>   down; automatic recovery in progress 2018-11-08 12:45:25.127 UTC [22]
>   LOG:  redo starts at 0/166CF68 2018-11-08 12:45:25.127 UTC [22] LOG: 
>   invalid record length at 0/166D048: wanted 24, got 0 2018-11-08
>   12:45:25.127 UTC [22] LOG:  redo done at 0/166D010 2018-11-08
>   12:45:25.259 UTC [22] PANIC:  could not rename file
>   "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp" to
>   "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint": Permission denied 2018-11-08
>   12:45:25.357 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 22) was terminated by
>   signal 6: Aborted 2018-11-08 12:45:25.358 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting
>   startup due to startup process failure 2018-11-08 12:45:25.359 UTC [1]
>   LOG:  database system is shut down

Can someone help me to sort it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

1. docker run --name ps-export -p 5432:5432 -i postgres
2. Connect to 5432 db, using dbeaver; create table; put some rows in the table
3. Make a dump (`data.sql`) to your host
4. Add in your `docker-compose.yml`, under the psql server

`

```
volumes:
- ./data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

5. `docker-compose up`

If you want to include `data.sql` in the image, instead of step 4, copy it to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql` in your dockerfile.

Comment: Thatnks! It didn't work exactly this way, but I changed a little bit and now it's working: - ./data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql and I added  environment to the docker-compose(POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD, POSTGRES_DB)